# Background application - Windows service or Form application without forms

Tags: c#

I want to create an application for myself that monitors time spent working with different programs (browser, MS office etc...) and saves collected data into database every x seconds.

After some research i came to 2 solutions : Windows service or Windows Form application without any forms (sort of background process).

I understand the basic difference between Windows service and normal application. The question is, what would you suggest considering RAM/CPU efficiency, also if there might be any critical aspects why not to use one or another solution.

Thank you

Comment: If it's should be running 24/7 then windows service.

Comment: How do you plan on communicating these statistics to the program? A Windows Service has very little access to the currently logged on user's profile. Literally, no interaction is permitted. From MSDN regarding services: `Windows Service applications run in a different window station than the interactive station of the logged-on user. A window station is a secure object that contains a Clipboard, a set of global atoms, and a group of desktop objects. ` See this link for more info. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @zugzwang - In my comment below my answer, I suggest he might think about a WCF service hosted inside a Windows Service.

Comment: I saw that, but you did not include that in your answer. You answer implies that it's possible to write it as a straight up Windows Service which I disagree with wholeheartedly. But, of course, this is dependent upon how he intends to communicate those stats.

Comment: this (background app) should only look for open and running applications and store data into database, absolutely no user interaction is needed. The data from database will be shown to user using another application win forms or maybe web application.

Comment: @zugzwang, I didn't include it in my answer because in his question, he never specified having to interact with it. I included it as a comment to my answer, because his comment suggested he may be communicating with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest difference between a Windows service and a Windows Form Application is that a Windows Service has no GUI or user interface.

What you need to ask yourself is, do you want this process to simply run in the background and dump the information in the database, or do you need some kind of user interaction?

If you need a user interface or some user interaction as the program is running, then a Windows form application would be better. If you want it to just do its job quietly in the background, go with a service. Also, a service can startup quietly with Windows and you can restrict access to who can uninstall the service.

As far as Memory or CPU usage, a service would consume less memory simply because a Windows form application has to allocate memory for at least one form, the main GUI form. Even if you hide this form, its still in memory (just not showing up visibly on the desktop).

From the requirements you specified in your question, I would go with a Windows Service.

Comment: As you said, this application should be as quiet as possible. there will be another application that will display the data. so yeah a service sounds good.

Comment: A third option you might want to consider is a [WCF Service hosted as a Windows service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.110).aspx). This will allow other programs, like a GUI Windows application, to communicate with your Windows Service. This will make it easier, in the long run, to make a GUI program later down the road to gather things such as statistics and what not.

Answer (score 0):

RAM/CPU would be almost the same

But suppose that one would take another K of memory, but the other (or not the other) would take another 20 nano-seconds to run... how would that change things for you? If it would - determine what values would be acceptable by you, then, if the program takes too lonq/too much memory - profile what takes most of the CPU-time/memory - and optimize that... This is not gonna be being the program win-form app, or win-service...

Win service would be slightly more difficult to debug (put `Debugger.Launch` or `Debugger.Break` in the beginning... here.. problem solved).

But I would prefer a win-service... I can't see why put win-forms app without forms... It's like having a car without wheels, because you need an engine... Why not just use an engine?! Why not use an engine designed to run in the background, which you can control when (or why) it starts, what permissions it has, etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you're only wanting "time spent on application" which I assume would be the amount of time a particular executable is running then Windows Service is definitely the way to go. The only thing I would caution you about is that the amount of a time a particular executable is running under a particular profile does not necessary represent the amount of time using it. Of course, the application can be running and minimized. In this case your recorder would be showing the application "in use" when it is, in fact, not being used.

I personally find Windows Services more enjoyable to write than WinForms. But, that's a matter of personal opinion.

Good luck,

Z